# How do I use OmniAuth with a Memcache store in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, omniauth

I would like to use Memcache for OmniAuth's store but I cannot find any examples on how to do this. Filesystem tmp is not working for my host. How can I convert the code in my omniauth.rb below to use Memcache. Also do I need any extra gems to get Memcache to work?

Thanks!!

**current omniauth.rb:**

```
require 'openid/store/filesystem'
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do    
    provider :open_id, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), {:name => "google", :domain => "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" }
end
```

Comment: as off the question it may be, if your host is Heroku, you just have to change `new('/tmp')` to `new('./tmp')`

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're on Heroku, since I went through some trouble with this too. I ran into some problems using the standard Memcached library on Heroku, though I don't recall what they were now. I wound up using [Dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) instead, which works great there.

Unfortunately, the default ruby-openid doesn't work with Dalli as a client, and doesn't appear to be actively maintained any longer. I have [a fork](https://github.com/chanks/ruby-openid) that both fixes that issue and can be used in a Gemfile too.

Anyway, the following should work for you:

Initializer:

```
require 'openid/store/memcache'

Rails.application.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :open_id, OpenID::Store::Memcache.new(Dalli::Client.new), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
end
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'dalli', '1.0.2'
gem 'ruby-openid', :git => 'git://github.com/chanks/ruby-openid.git', :ref => '9ec3b76'
```

Sorry, I know that this is a pain. If you find a better solution, please let me know!

Comment: awesome, tks! that was exactly my problem and this solves it, except by the fact that you can now use the omniauth gem, which integrates with dalli without problems https://github.com/intridea/omniauth